# Multiple span tabucline not aligned

Tags: tabu

We used different span line with different rule thickness and color, when we used multiple
span lines in the same row, rules not aligned properly using tabu.

We know tabu not maintained currently, is there any possible solution to fixing this?

My MWE file:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{Tabu}


\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}%\PBS
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}%\PBS
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\RaggedLeft\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}%\PBS

\newtabulinestyle{TabuSolidOne=1pt}
\def\TabuDotted{\hbox{$\scriptstyle.$}}
\def\TabuStar{\hbox{$\scriptstyle\star$}}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
\caption{Star, Asterisk, Bullet, Double Line, Dotted, Dashed, and Solid}{\begin{tabu}{L{80pt}C{60pt}C{49pt}C{49pt}C{90pt}}
\tabucline{-}
\multicolumn{1}{C{80pt}}{ Period} &  6 months &  1 year &  18 months &  2 years\\
\tabucline{1-1}\tabucline{2-2}\tabucline{4-4}
\multicolumn{1}{C{80pt}}{ Period} &  6 months &  1 year &  18 months &  2 years\\
\tabucline[TabuSolidOne]{1-1}\tabucline[TabuSolidOne]{2-2}\tabucline[TabuSolidOne]{4-4}
\multicolumn{1}{C{80pt}}{ Period} &  6 months &  1 year &  18 months &  2 years\\
\tabucline[\TabuDotted]{1-1}\tabucline[\TabuDotted]{2-2}\tabucline[\TabuDotted]{4-4}
\multicolumn{1}{C{80pt}}{ Period} &  6 months &  1 year &  18 months &  2 years\\
\tabucline[\TabuStar]{1-1}\tabucline[\TabuStar]{2-2}\tabucline[\TabuStar]{4-4}
\multicolumn{1}{C{80pt}}{ Period} &  6 months &  1 year &  18 months &  2 years\\
\tabucline{-}
\end{tabu}}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!h]
\caption{Star, Asterisk, Bullet, Double Line, Dotted, Dashed, and Solid}{\tabulinesep4pt\begin{tabu}{L{80pt}C{60pt}C{49pt}C{49pt}C{90pt}}
\tabucline{-}
\multicolumn{1}{C{80pt}}{ Period} &  6 months &  1 year &  18 months &  2 years\\
\tabucline{1-1}\tabucline{2-2}\tabucline{4-4}
\multicolumn{1}{C{80pt}}{ Period} &  6 months &  1 year &  18 months &  2 years\\
\tabucline[TabuSolidOne]{1-1}\tabucline[TabuSolidOne]{2-2}\tabucline[TabuSolidOne]{4-4}
\multicolumn{1}{C{80pt}}{ Period} &  6 months &  1 year &  18 months &  2 years\\
\tabucline[\TabuDotted]{1-1}\tabucline[\TabuDotted]{2-2}\tabucline[\TabuDotted]{4-4}
\multicolumn{1}{C{80pt}}{ Period} &  6 months &  1 year &  18 months &  2 years\\
\tabucline[\TabuStar]{1-1}\tabucline[\TabuStar]{2-2}\tabucline[\TabuStar]{4-4}
\multicolumn{1}{C{80pt}}{ Period} &  6 months &  1 year &  18 months &  2 years\\
\tabucline{-}
\end{tabu}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Which LaTeX version are you using. When using a version after December 2018 please have a look how it has been solved for doxygen: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/6769 maybe this works for you as well or gives you some ideas how to fix it.

Comment: We using TeXLive 2017 and also compared "tabu.sty"  and "tabu_doxygen.sty" both are same version, in the provided link no such question found.

Comment: It was a wild guess, it might have been a problem with an update, but unfortunately it is not (most of the times the update results in a crash).

Comment: Well if you want to fix it, the best would be to find a new maintainer.  But consider this comment first https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu/issues/23#issuecomment-559777661